# Delete a specific row from datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to delete a specific row from datatable. When adding the last row, I need to delete the yellow colored rows. It is very easy to Select from a datatable like below

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("STOK_KODU='HAMMADDE_2'");
```

I was wondering if there is a way like below to delete ??? Or would you advice an easy way to delete a rows from datatable?

```
dt.Delete("STOK_KODU='HAMMADDE_2'");
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the rows from the in memory datatable or do you want to remove them from the backend database table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to recreate the table with the rows you want to keep:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("STOK_KODU") != "HAMMADDE_2")
    .CopyToDataTable()
```

The other is to use `DataRowCollection.Remove`:

```
DataRow[] rowsToRemove = dt.Select("STOK_KODU='HAMMADDE_2'");
foreach (var rowToDelete in rowsToRemove)
    dt.Rows.Remove(rowToDelete);
```

The second approach is more efficient if you want to delete few rows and the table is large. The first approach using LINQ is more powerful since you can use any code but it can be less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `Rows` collection of the `DataTable`:

```
foreach (var row in dr)
    dt.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ::

```
DataRow[] rows;
rows=dt.Select("STOK_KODU='HAMMADDE_2'"); 
foreach(DataRow r in rows)
r.Delete();
```

Comment: This will not remove the rows from the table and it will also not delete the rows in the database (without using a `DataAdapter`). It will just set the rowstate to `Deleted` which is a flag for a `DataAdapter`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was just writing about it. But [the fastest gun in the west](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) has hit again :-))

Comment: @ayilmaz Tim is right, if you want to remove rows, then you should use `Rows.Remove`

Answer (score 1):

Deleting rows from an in memory DataTable object is really easy

```
dt.Select("STOK_KODU='HAMMADDE_2'").AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Delete());
```

However you should consider that the Delete method simply marks the RowState to Deleted, but the rows are still in the DataTable.Rows collection. To really remove them you need to call

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

without this call, if you loop over the datatable rows collection, you need to check the RowState to avoid an error message stating that you cannot access the information of a deleted row

```
foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{

    if(r.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)    
         Console.WriteLine(r[0].ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: `DataTable.AcceptChanges` does not remove the rows which have `RowState=Deleted`. It will make the `RowState=Unchanged`. It's just a flag for a `DataAdapter` which wil call `AcceptChanges` itself after it has updated the datasource. You can check that easily by inspecting `dt.GetChanges()` in the debugger before and after you've called `AcceptChanges`.